# Node JS (Electron) | find unresolved 3rd party promise in runtime

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, electron

In some rare case my grpc stream get stack waiting for unresolved promise inside a 3rd-party library code

I wish to find a way, in runtime or after, to find the line with the unresolved promise (async-await call), but I couldn't find a way to do it electron (chromium) dev tools or a third party utility, and since it's a third party code I cant use an interceptor.

unresolved promise example:

```
async function thirdPartyFunc() {
    console.log("t1");
    await new Promise((resolve)=>{});
    console.log("will never happen");
}

(async ()=>{await thirdPartyFunc()})();
```

any ideas of how I can do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "*I cant use an interceptor*"?

Comment: it's not my code, it's a compiled js. @Bergi if you think that I still can, please tell me how! will be much appricated

Comment: What is an "interceptor", and how would you use it to debug this issue if it was your own code?

Comment: When the stream gets stuck, are you sure it's not just legitimately waiting for a message from the remote end?

Comment: actually the issue was fixed!
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/2604#issuecomment-1779632723